# Boost.Python: Weak reference to object?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

Is there a way to get a weak reference to a Python object? With boost::python::object you get a strong/shared reference so as long as either C++ or Python holds a reference to that object, it will not get deleted. I want only Python to hold a strong reference to an object, and C++ a weak one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go into the CPython API for that. Use `PyWeakReference` type from `weakrefobject.h`. The header exposes an API that's similar to `weakref` module — see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/weakref.html).

Comment: Thanks. I used weakref in my scripts, instead of going into the C API. The scripts are now a little harder to write, but following the Zen of Python, 'Explicit is better than implicit'. :)